# Select * from two tables into two separate lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

Basic idea in psuedocode

`Select(a, b) => new Tuple<List<Item1>, List<Item2>>(a, b)`

I am trying to accomplish this in:

- A single query to the db
- obviously using linq (query or method syntax)

Here are the two classes involved

```
public class Bundle
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Right now all I can think of is

```
 using (var context = new MyEntities())
 {
     return new Tuple<IEnumerable<Inventory>, IEnumerable<Bundle>>(context.Inventories.OrderBy(a => a.Stock).ToList()
         , context.Bundles.Include(b => b.Inventories).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList());
 }
```

However, this would hit the database twice.

I know `UNION` is used to combine result sets from 2 different queries but the two queries must have the same # of columns so I'm assuming it's best used when selecting the same data.

**How can I select data from two different tables into two separate lists with only ONE hit on the db?**

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to hit just one time the database?

Comment: Just to minimize the amount of queries executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about performance, I don't think that reducing the amount of queries is the way to go. In fact, if you want fine-grain optimizations, LINQ isn't the most appropriate tool, either.

That being said, you could make the two different objects match the same interface/columns, filling with dummy properties for those missing in the other type. This should theoretically be translated to a SQL `union` containing all of the columns.

```
var union = context.Inventories
    .Select(i => new { i.Id, i.Name, i.Stock, Inventories=null })
    .Concat(context.Bundles.Select(b => new { b.Id, b.Name, Stock=0, b.Inventories));
```

Note that in this case [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) is preferred over of [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union(v=vs.110).aspx), as it doesn't alter the order of your rows and allows duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you want two result sets, you can do it by throwing two queries. This can be done in a single database call without issue, but it won't magically divide into two sets of objects as you are interested in.

In fact, asking more than one question and getting more than one result set is very common when the cost of establishing connection (instantiation cost or latency cost, etc.) is great enough to warrant it. I have done it myself in a stored procedure, asking for everything a page needs in one query.

But, if performance is the key issue, caching is also very common. And, if these are drop down lists, or something else where the list requested is small, and the list does not change often, you can even pull it into memory when the application starts and let it set on the web server so you are not making the database trip.

I am not fond of LINQ to SQL, as it creates a mess for DBAs, but you can do it something like this (just one example, any method where you can chain commands will work):

```
var connString = "{conn string here}";
var commandString = "select * from tableA; select * from tableB";
var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn);
try {
    conn.Open();
    var result = command.Execute();
    // work with results here
}
finally {
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

I have not filled in all of the details, but you can do this with any number of commands. Once again, if the information does not change, consider a single hit and holding in memory (caching through programming) or using some other type of cache mechanism.

Comment: Gregory, I appreciate your well thought out response but I had to mark Sam's answer as correct as he showed a possible solution using linq. Nevertheless, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Adrian - No problem. The issue I have with LINQ to SQL is the nightmare is causes for DBAs. Not bad for a small project, but not so good in Enterprise situations. I am not against LINQ itself, as I find it a very good way to comb through objects. What is funny is LINQ to SQL was written largely due to the delay in SQL Server 2005 (Entity Framework 1.0) and a demo highlighting how to build a website in 15 minutes at the launch of Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible.
If you are trying to get two distinct results you need to hit the DB twice, once per result set. You can do an outer join, but this would make your result set larger than it should, and judging from the fact that you want to hit the DB once, you care about performance.
Also, if performance was an issue, I would not use Linq in the first place.

Comment: I agree with you on the linq point. This project is just a takehome from an interview so I'm trying to foresee any 'gotchas' I may run into. That's strange though, I would have thought there'd be a way to do this in one go.

Comment: Ahhh interview questions usually make no sense:)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do this by asking for multiple result sets (as Gregory pointed out already), I am not sure though what would be the "best" way for this. Why don't you take a look at this msdn article for example?
[How to: Use Stored Procedures Mapped for Multiple Result Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399371(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or this, for a linq-to-sql approach:
[LINQ to SQL: returning multiple result sets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/swiss_dpe_team/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets/)